# dotnet-gcdump timeout parameter not taken into account

Tags: .net, dump

I wonder if someone else ever had this problem with dotnet-gcdump. If I'm right, we can copy the executable on a server by downloading the standalone version.

I enter the following command on the prompt :

```
.\dotnet-gcdump.exe collect -t 120 -p pid -o file.dmp -v
```

I get a timeout exception after 30 seconds even if I specified 120 seconds.

Thanks